# How to make Voiceover to spell each letter in a word?

Tags: ios, swift, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have a text `CPN34THX` which should be read by voiceover as `C N 3 4 T H X`
Is there any property to be set to `UIAccessibility` so that it can be read character by character?

Comment: did you try adding space between characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### iOS 13 and above

You should use `.accessibilitySpeechSpellOut` or `.accessibilitySpeechIPANotation.` instead to make it spelling

---

#### iOS 12 and earlear

Set the `accessibilityLabel` separately as you needed.

```
let code = "CPN34THX"
let accessibleCode = code.map { String($0) + " " }.joined() // output: "C P N 3 4 T H X"
myLabel.text = code
myLabel.accessibilityLabel = accessibleCode
```

For making it more pronounceable, make a string like this:

```
myLabel.accessibilityLabel = "C^. P^. N^. 3. 4. T^. H^. X^."
```

Comment: That text is not a static one.

Comment: You can use some functions to build that. Answer Updated @ramgandhi

Comment: Please don't do this: adding Spaces or Special Characters just for Speech will mess up with other Accessibility Types like Braille. Use the appropriate types with an Attributed String, like mentioned in @goldengil's answer, e.g. `.accessibilitySpeechSpellOut` or `.accessibilitySpeechIPANotation`.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using the `NSAttributedString.Key.accessibilitySpeechSpellOut`
to make `VoiceOver` read each letter separately.

From `UIAccessibilityConstants.h`:

```swift
// Use an NSNumber with a YES or NO value to specify whether each letter in the string should be spoken separately.
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    public static let accessibilitySpeechSpellOut: NSAttributedString.Key
```

Pay attention this is only available from iOS 13 and above.

An example:

```swift
let string = "CPN34THX"
let attributedLabel = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string,
                                                attributes:[.accessibilitySpeechSpellOut: true])
yourAccessibleView.accessibilityAttributedLabel =  attributedLabel
```

Comment: This is how you do it the right way.